# How to determine the size of an icon from a HICON?

Tags: winapi, icons

I have an icon identified by an `HICON` handle that I want to draw centered on a custom control.

How do I determine the size of the icon so that I can calculate the correct drawing position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Win32 `GetIconInfo` call will return, as part of its response, the icon's source bitmap.  You can get the icon image size from this.

```vb
Dim IconInf As IconInfo
Dim BMInf As Bitmap

If (GetIconInfo(hIcon, IconInf)) Then
    If (IconInf.hbmColor) Then ' Icon has colour plane
        If (GetObject(IconInf.hbmColor, Len(BMInf), BMInf)) Then
            Width = BMInf.bmWidth
            Height = BMInf.bmHeight
            BitDepth = BMInf.bmBitsPixel
        End If

        Call DeleteObject(IconInf.hbmColor)
    Else ' Icon has no colour plane, image data stored in mask
        If (GetObject(IconInf.hbmMask, Len(BMInf), BMInf)) Then
            Width = BMInf.bmWidth
            Height = BMInf.bmHeight \ 2
            BitDepth = 1
        End If
    End If

    Call DeleteObject(IconInf.hbmMask)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine with my color icons. What is the purpose of "Height = BMInf.bmHeight \ 2" in the mask-case?

Comment: @Timbo: see msdn:ICONINFO, a monochrome icon contains image and XOR mask in the hbmMask.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a C++ version of code:

```
struct MYICON_INFO
{
    int     nWidth;
    int     nHeight;
    int     nBitsPerPixel;
};

MYICON_INFO MyGetIconInfo(HICON hIcon);

// =======================================

MYICON_INFO MyGetIconInfo(HICON hIcon)
{
    MYICON_INFO myinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&myinfo, sizeof(myinfo));

    ICONINFO info;
    ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));

    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    bRes = GetIconInfo(hIcon, &info);
    if(!bRes)
        return myinfo;

    BITMAP bmp;
    ZeroMemory(&bmp, sizeof(bmp));

    if(info.hbmColor)
    {
        const int nWrittenBytes = GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);
        if(nWrittenBytes > 0)
        {
            myinfo.nWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
            myinfo.nHeight = bmp.bmHeight;
            myinfo.nBitsPerPixel = bmp.bmBitsPixel;
        }
    }
    else if(info.hbmMask)
    {
        // Icon has no color plane, image data stored in mask
        const int nWrittenBytes = GetObject(info.hbmMask, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);
        if(nWrittenBytes > 0)
        {
            myinfo.nWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
            myinfo.nHeight = bmp.bmHeight / 2;
            myinfo.nBitsPerPixel = 1;
        }
    }

    if(info.hbmColor)
        DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
    if(info.hbmMask)
        DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);

    return myinfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python version of the code:

```py
import win32gui

hIcon = some_icon
info = win32gui.GetIconInfo(hIcon)

if info:
    if info[4]: # Icon has colour plane
        bmp = win32gui.GetObject(info[4])
        
        if bmp:
            Width = bmp.bmWidth
            Height = bmp.bmHeight
            BitDepth = bmp.bmBitsPixel
    else: # Icon has no colour plane, image data stored in mask
        bmp = win32gui.GetObject(info[4])
        
        if bmp:
            Width = bmp.bmWidth
            Height = bmp.bmHeight // 2
            BitDepth = 1

    info[3].close()
    info[4].close()
```