# HICON/HBITMAP to QIcon/QPixmap/QImage/Anything with a Q in it

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to get 48x48 or 256x256 icons from files in Windows and have come across what seems like a dead-end. At the moment I have a HICON handle(since PySides QFileIconProvider only returns 32x32 icons) in python which I would like to show in a pyside window but functions like QPixmap.fromHICON/HBITMAP are not implemented and also seems to have been removed from the source since Qt 4.8(?). Also, I'm trying to avoid having to save the icon to a file.

So, is there any way to get a HICON or possibly any other things you can turn it into, to any kind of PySide object?

EDIT:
I've been trying to simply rewrite the old function fromWinHBITMAP function in python but it isn't going great. I'm uncertain how I should translate the src line into python and I don't either have any idea how I change the value of the memory buffer returned by QImage.scanLine()

```
for (int y=0; y<h; ++y) {
            QRgb *dest = (QRgb *) image.scanLine(y);
            const QRgb *src = (const QRgb *) (data + y * bytes_per_line);
            for (int x=0; x<w; ++x) {
                dest[x] = src[x] | mask;
            }
        }
```

At the moment I create a PyCBITMAP from the HICON with the win32api and retrieves the list of bits.

```
for y in range(0, hIcon.height):
    dest = i.scanLine(y)
    src = bitmapbits[y*hIcon.widthBytes:(y*hIcon.widthBytes)+hIcon.widthBytes]

    for x in range(0, hIcon.width):
        dest[x] = bytes(ctypes.c_uint32(src[x] | 0))
```

This results in "ValueError: cannot modify size of memoryview object"

The source for the function be found here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/19188-Converting-from-HBitmap-to-a-QPixmap?p=94747#post94747

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

```
def iconToQImage(hIcon):
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, hIcon.width, hIcon.height)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)

    win32gui.DrawIconEx(hdc.GetHandleOutput(), 0, 0, hIcon.hIcon, hIcon.width, hIcon.height, 0, None, 0x0003)

    bitmapbits = hbmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    image = QtGui.QImage(bitmapbits, hIcon.width, hIcon.height, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    return image
```

Comment: How do you get your hIcon handle in the first place?

Comment: Made a python module in c++ using the windows & shellapi headers if I remember correctly. Though I guess it's possible to do the same thing in python with ctypes.windll. http://pogopixels.com/blog/getting-the-48x48-or-256x256-icon-of-a-file-on-windows/

Comment: I was just wondering since you had the properties of hIcon like width and height but a custom wrapper would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to get this sort of setup going but from I read around Python Imaging Library (PIL) supports [bitmap and ICO files](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) and has [downloads for Windows](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). Assuming you can get a filename of the icon, you can load it up with PIL and then transfer the [raw data to a QImage](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5866/#35038):

```
from PIL import Image
from PySide.QtGui import QImage, QImageReader, QLabel, QPixmap, QApplication

im = Image.open("my_image.png")
data = im.tostring('raw', 'RGBA')

app = QApplication([])

image = QImage(data, im.size[0], im.size[1], QImage.Format_ARGB32)
pix = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
lbl = QLabel()
lbl.setPixmap(pix)
lbl.show()

app.exec_()
```

Then work with whatever `QImage` operation you need to do from there.

Comment: If you could get a filename of the icon, you could just call `image = QImage(); image.load(filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

While @egs0's answer is accurate, trying to display the output may cause problems because `QLabel` doesn't handle bitmap very well. To solve these problems, convert the result to another image format.

```py
import win32ui
import win32gui
# Doesn't matter which library. Qt5 should work just as well.
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore

def iconToQImage(hIcon, width, height, im_format="PNG"):
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)

    win32gui.DrawIconEx(hdc.GetHandleOutput(), 0, 0, hIcon, width, height, 0, None, 0x0003)

    bitmapbits = hbmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    image = QtGui.QImage(bitmapbits, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    
    # Write to and then load from a buffer to convert to PNG.
    buffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
    buffer.setOpenMode(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    image.save(buffer, im_format)
    image.loadFromData(buffer.data(), im_format)
    
    # Use QtGui.Pixmap.fromImage() to get a pixmap instead.
    return image
```

It's also possible to get the size of an icon using the following function, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913468/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-icon-from-a-hicon):

```py
def getIconSize(HIcon):
    info = win32gui.GetIconInfo(HIcon)
    
    if info[4]:  # Icon has color plane.
        bmp = win32gui.GetObject(info[4])

        width = bmp.bmWidth
        height = bmp.bmHeight
    else: # Icon has no colour plane, image data stored in mask.
        bmp = win32gui.GetObject(info[3])

        width = bmp.width 
        height = bmp.height // 2  # A monochrome icon contains image and XOR mask in the hbmMask.

    info[3].close()
    info[4].close()

    return width, height
```