# Convert HICON to QIcon in Qt 6

Tags: c++, winapi, qt6

I'm trying to convert a HICON to a QIcon/QPixmap in Qt6. In older Qt versions there used to be a [fromHICON](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwin.html#fromHICON) function that made this conversion very easy. Unfortunately, they removed it in Qt6 so I tried to do it myself following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331019/15907116):

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 32, 32);
hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(hdc, hbitmap);

// Calculate size of buffer
BITMAP BitmapInfo = {0};
DWORD BitmapImageSize = BitmapInfo.bmHeight * BitmapInfo.bmWidth * (BitmapInfo.bmBitsPixel / 8);

// Allocate memory
BYTE *pBitmapData = new BYTE[BitmapImageSize];
ZeroMemory(pBitmapData, BitmapImageSize);

// Get Bitmap data
GetBitmapBits(hbitmap, BitmapImageSize, pBitmapData);

QImage image = QImage(pBitmapData, 32, 32, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
ui->label->setScaledContents(true);

// delete data
delete[] pBitmapData;
```

However, I must have messed something up. The image is just some random noise and sometimes the application also crashes.

[Displayed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1uA.png)

Additional info: The icon is aquired like this:

```
HICON icon = (HICON)GetClassLong(hwnd, -14);
```

Comment: [To convert a QPixmap to and from HICON you can use the QtWinExtras functions QtWin::toHICON() and QtWin::fromHICON() respectively.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpixmap.html)

Comment: QtWinExtras is not available in Qt6 so I can't use that. [See](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew60.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QT 6, the implementation (minus a convert to QPixmap) for QtWin::fromHICON() has moved into a static function for QImage.
So now you just need to.

```
  QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage::fromHICON(icon));
```