# Detect size of HICON with JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

My final goal is to obtain the icon of a HWND in Java with help of JNA library. Everything works fine except of one important thing: I need the size of the icon for further processing steps in Java.

It seems that I cannot request the size. I always obtain the size 0x0. What am I doing wrong? The basic code example looks like the following. Most API function templates were not part of JNA. So, I had to define them on my own.

```
    final long hicon = ExtUser32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(hwnd, ExtUser32.WM_GETICON, ExtUser32.ICON_BIG, 0);
    final Pointer hIcon = new Pointer(hicon);
    final ICONINFO info = new ICONINFO();
    final BITMAP bmp = new BITMAP();
    final SIZE size = new SIZE();

    System.out.println(ExtUser32.INSTANCE.GetIconInfo(hIcon, info));
    System.out.println(info);
    System.out.println(ExtGdi32.INSTANCE.GetBitmapDimensionEx(info.hbmColor, size));
    System.out.println(size);

    if (info.hbmColor != null)
    {
        final int nWrittenBytes = ExtGdi32.INSTANCE.GetObjectA(info.hbmColor, bmp.size(), bmp.getPointer());
        System.out.println(nWrittenBytes);
        System.out.println(bmp);
    }
```

The sysouts print this:

```
true
ICONINFO(auto-allocated@0x5b72b4f0 (32 bytes)) {
  WinDef$BOOL fIcon@0=1
  WinDef$DWORD xHotspot@4=16
  WinDef$DWORD yHotspot@8=16
  WinDef$HBITMAP hbmMask@10=native@0xffffffffb00515e8 (com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$HBITMAP@b00515e7)
  WinDef$HBITMAP hbmColor@18=native@0xffffffffa50515c8 (com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$HBITMAP@a50515c7)
}
true
WinUser$SIZE(auto-allocated@0x652a3000 (8 bytes)) {
  int cx@0=0
  int cy@4=0
}
32
BITMAP(auto-allocated@0x5b72b5b0 (32 bytes)) {
  WinDef$LONG bmType@0=0
  WinDef$LONG bmWidth@4=0
  WinDef$LONG bmHeight@8=0
  WinDef$LONG bmWidthBytes@c=0
  WinDef$WORD bmPlanes@10=0
  WinDef$WORD bmBitsPixel@12=0
  WinDef$LPVOID bmBits@18=0
}
```

The request of ICONINFO structure seems to be correct. But if I try to request the dimension for the set `hbmColor` structure component by `Gdi32.GetBitmapDimensionEx()` then the structure keeps initialized with zeros. This approach via `hbmColor` or `hbmMask` was suggested by:

[How to determine the size of an icon from a HICON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913468/how-to-determine-the-size-of-an-icon-from-a-hicon)

**UPDATE 1**

Error tracing added!

As the sysouts indicate (`true`), the concerning function invocations didn't fail.

**UPDATE 2**

Further observation: In Java, these recreated structure types are intialized with zeros after instantiation. I set the initial values of the structure components in SIZE and BITMAP to a value that deviates from zero. `GetBitmapDimensionEx` sets it back to zero. But `GetObjectA` doesn't modify the structure! The function's return result indicates that bytes were written but that's not true!

```
        ...
        size.cx = 1;
        size.cy = 2;

        bmp.bmType.setValue(1);
        bmp.bmWidth.setValue(2);
        bmp.bmHeight.setValue(3);
        bmp.bmWidthBytes.setValue(4);
        bmp.bmPlanes.setValue(5);
        bmp.bmBitsPixel.setValue(6);
        bmp.bmBits.setValue(7);

        System.out.println(ExtGdi32.INSTANCE.GetBitmapDimensionEx(info.hbmColor, size));
        System.out.println(size);

        if (info.hbmColor != null)
        {
            final int nWrittenBytes = ExtGdi32.INSTANCE.GetObjectA(info.hbmColor, bmp.size(), bmp.getPointer());
            System.out.println(nWrittenBytes);
            System.out.println(bmp);
        }
```

Results:

```
true
WinUser$SIZE(auto-allocated@0x64fbcb20 (8 bytes)) {
  int cx@0=0
  int cy@4=0
}
32
BITMAP(auto-allocated@0x64fb91f0 (32 bytes)) {
  WinDef$LONG bmType@0=1
  WinDef$LONG bmWidth@4=2
  WinDef$LONG bmHeight@8=3
  WinDef$LONG bmWidthBytes@c=4
  WinDef$WORD bmPlanes@10=5
  WinDef$WORD bmBitsPixel@12=6
  WinDef$LPVOID bmBits@18=7
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any error checking? Why did you not check for errors?

Comment: I'm going to do it later (also releasing of resources). I wanted to keep this example short.

Comment: You have to check for errors now. Please do that and update the question.

Comment: Another question: Does the detection of the icon's size work anyway with JNA?

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added this as a comment but my reputation is too low:

You are not showing your BITMAP or GetObjectA definitions so I'm guessing but
in your line:

```
        final int nWrittenBytes = ExtGdi32.INSTANCE.GetObjectA(info.hbmColor, bmp.size(), bmp.getPointer());
```

you fail to call 'bmp.read()' afterwards.

If you look at the javadoc for Struture.getPointer()

https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html

you see that you are responsible for calling Structure.write() and Structure.read() before and after making the call to native method that uses a pointer obtained with getPointer(). In your case the write is superfluous but it is a good practice.

To understand why this is necessary consider that your BITMAP/bmp object is a Java object living in Java heap where it can get moved around during garbage collection. Hence the getPointer() cannot return the real address of the 'real' object. Instead it returns a pointer to a separate fixed (non movable) chunk of memory in the native heap (which chunk JNA allocates and associates with your Java object. Now your getObjectA() routine will write its stuff to *that* memory but JNA or anyone on the java side cannot have a clue that this is what happens. So you need to call the read() to tell JNA to copy the native side stuff to the Java object.

Comment: This sounds reasonable and it was the solution! Thank you very much! This is an important knowledge about structures under JNA that everybody needs to know!

Answer (score 0):

### If this is a 32-bit application only:

Your `BITMAP` structure is incorrect. Here's a simple C program that prints the expected offsets of all the fields of `BITMAP`, and its total size:

```
// 24 january 2015
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof (BITMAP));
#define O(f) printf("%s %x\n", #f, offsetof(BITMAP, f))
    O(bmType);
    O(bmWidth);
    O(bmHeight);
    O(bmWidthBytes);
    O(bmPlanes);
    O(bmBitsPixel);
    O(bmBits);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's what I get (in wine, compiled as a 32-bit program with MinGW-w64):

```
24
bmType 0
bmWidth 4
bmHeight 8
bmWidthBytes c
bmPlanes 10
bmBitsPixel 12
bmBits 14
```

Notice that your Java output above has a different size for `BITMAP` and a different offset for `bmBits`.

**(The `BITMAP` structure is correct for 64-bit applications.)**

### General:

Why `GetObject()` is indicating success is beyond me.

I don't know JNA at all so I don't know what to do about this. Does JNA not provide a `WinGDI$BITMAP`?